# Django: HttpResponseRedirect with ID

Tags: django

Hi at the end of saving an object I redirect the user to the edit page. I'm new to Django and below is how I currently achieve this. Is this the correct way? Or is there a better way I don't know about yet?

Thanks.

```
 if form.is_valid():
            group.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Successfully Created/Updated Group')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contacts/group/edit/%s' % group.pk)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the 'django' way of doing this is by using the [get_absolute_url() function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url).  Are you using class-based views?  I believe the default behavior of the Create/Update view is to redirect to the get_absolute_url of the created/updated object instance.